# How many solutions possible for the equation $x + 2y + 3z = 25\;?$

Tags: combinatorics

> How many solutions possible for the equation $x+2y+3z=25\;?$
> $x,\,y,\,z\geqslant0 $

I would like to know how to solve such equations in general.
That is, to solve equations where we have to find the number of solutions to the equation:
$$Ax + By + Cz = n$$

Comment: Are you asking "How many real solutions?" or "How many integer solutions?" or "How many integer solutions with all components positive integers?"

Comment: Integer solutions

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you are looking for the number of *integer* solutions.

In general the number is the coefficient at $x^n$ in the power series of:
$$
\frac1{1-x^A}\cdot\frac1{1-x^B}\cdot\frac1{1-x^C}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean integer solutions. Rewrite it as $2y+3z=25-x$ so the RHS can be any integer between $0$ and $25$. Now for a fixed RHS $0\le z' \le 25$, try to solve $2x+3y=z'$. This is equivalent to asking for a fixed $z'$, if you take away a multiple of $3$ (you know how many such multiples there are $\le z'$) whether the result is still even. For some parity of $z'$ you know how many multiples of $3$ less than or equal to it are of the same parity. Its easier to count from here.